# Don't allow typing numbers between max and min value

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience

I'm working on an Angular 4 project. I have an HTML `<input type="number">` with `min` `max` and `step` attributes. My goal is to prevent typing numbers beyond the min-max range that is user friendly. How can I do that?

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    var min = -100;
    var max = 100;

    var txtValue = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var pressedValue = e.key;

    var combined = parseFloat(txtValue, pressedValue);
    console.log(`OLD:${txtValue}\nNEW:${pressedValue}\nCOMBINED:${combined}`);
    if (combined > max) {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('ohhw snapp');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txt" value="Hello" onkeydown="myFunction(event)" min="-100" max="100" step="0.05">
```

My [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/q94bgL4k/5/)

Comment: You can't stop someone typing in an incorrect value. Instead provide feedback to them explaining what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For UX reasons, I'd recommend something more like this. It may confuse the user if they just think their keyboard is not working.

```js
$('.range-enforced').on('change', function(e){
  var min=parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));
  var max=parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
  var curr=parseFloat($(this).val());
  if (curr > max) { $(this).val(max); var changed=true; }
  if (curr < min) { $(this).val(min); var changed=true; }
  if (changed) {
    $warning = $(this).siblings('.warning')
    $warning.text('Only ' + min + ' through ' + max + ' allowed');
    $warning.show()
    $warning.fadeOut(2500);
  }
});
```

```css
input + .warning {
  background: #ffff99;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="range-enforced" min="-100" max="100" />
<div class="warning" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have an answer that doesn\t use jQuery?

Comment: I don't have one on hand (I typically don't write much non-library JavaScript), but this should be possible outside of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is you are providing 2 parameters to [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which only accepts 1 (maybe you got confused with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which takes 2 parameters- a string and a radix. You should combine the numbers first and do 1 parse float on the combined value.

for example

```js
function myFunction() {
  var min = -100;
  var max = 100;
  
  var inputRef = document.getElementById("txt");
  var txtValue = inputRef.value;
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(txtValue))){
    console.log("warning input is not a number");
    return;
  }
  var newNum = parseFloat(txtValue);
  console.log(`NEW:${newNum}`);
  if (newNum > max || newNum < min) {
    console.log('input not in range (' + min + ", " + max + ")");
    inputRef.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txt"
        onkeyup="myFunction()"
        min="-100"
        max="100"
        step="0.05"
        >
```

The input will reset back to empty now if the input is not in range on keyup. As per the comment above you can use this to notify the user of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, very good approach.
But it isn't possible to type a value with point. eg: '15.65'

Comment: I fixed the sample to use floats as well

Comment: I updated the example to reset the input to empty if the user enters a number not in the range. It would be nice to also tell the user what went wrong in some fashion.