# Angular 4 input[type='number'] prevent typing over min/max

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a `inputNumber` directive which will prevent typing (not highlighting the input when value is wrong, but even **typing in** wrong value):

a) letters and symbols, restrict only to [0-9]
b) respect `min` and `max` params
c) be in relation with other such directives in the view via `greaterOrEqual` / `lessOrEqual` properties.

This is my `input-number.directive.ts`:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[inputNumber]'
})
export class InputNumberDirective {

    @Input() min: number = 0; // will be input
    @Input() max: number = 100; // will be input

    @Input() greaterOrEqual: number = 23; // will be input
    @Input() lessOrEqual: number = 77; // will be input

    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) sanitizeValue(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {

        const targetVal: number = Number((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);

        if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode < 58) {
            if (this.min !== null && targetVal < this.min) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.max !== null && targetVal > this.max) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.greaterOrEqual !== null && targetVal < this.greaterOrEqual) {
                return false;
            }
            return !(this.lessOrEqual !== null && targetVal > this.lessOrEqual);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This all works in terms of preventing typing letters/symbols, but when it comes to respecting numbers limiters user is still able to type them over and my purpose to prevent this.
I found some SO threads (e.g. [Don't allow typing numbers between max and min value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325574/dont-allow-typing-numbers-between-max-and-min-value)) on this, but it didn't help me a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't is be easier to write your own validator?

Comment: Validator will not prevent typing in wrong value

Comment: But could prevent submiting a form

Comment: This is two way binding case where data is used later dynamically

Comment: personally, I would redesign that.

Comment: Use a regex to check the input. Also, don't forget to check the value in the `paste` event.

Comment: I am open to suggestions, that's why I here :)

Comment: here everything would be fine, if I could intercept value before it's displayed in the input field, this works for preventing certain keys hit, but not for value

Comment: You could use a [slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a directive ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfbv7q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirective.ts))I am sure will help your case, it doesn´t let other input values other than numbers but also it allows CTRL+C, CTRL+V among other usefull keys for inputs.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[NumericInput]'
})
export class NumericInput {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input() latestInputValue: number;

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;

            if (this.latestInputValue < 0 || this.latestInputValue > 100) {
              e.preventDefault();
            } else if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
              // let it happen, don't do anything
              return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<input NumericInput [latestInputValue]="someValue" [(ngModel)]="someValue" >
```

Comment: thanks for you effort, but my main concern is to resolve typing over min and max values, this is missing in your answer

Comment: edited answer, you should now get input value in latestInputValue so you can validate it

Comment: so mate? This should be enough to make your case work... any feedback?

Comment: the feedback is as I have mentioned already this is a good example of handling junk data to input number field, but please do read what I am looking for and what the questions stands about... my issue is only partially related to what you suggest, my main concern is how to prevent typing over min/max values... I appreciate your effort but I cannot even upvote it as it's not what I need

Comment: Ok but just in case are you sure it doesn´t work to limit a min-max input after the edit with validation if (latestInputValue < 0 || latestInputValue > 100) { ???

Comment: I eventually redesigned this logic and wrapped the input directive in a component, added increment/decrement functionality and value validation, but you were close :) tnx

Comment: This is really allowing me to start thinking in terms of the "Angular Way"

Comment: This allows pasting of characters :/

Comment: @Mohan remove the line under '// Allow: Ctrl+V' If you still want to paste only numbers, just add the logic where if you have a char you wont return the value

Answer (score 3):

Your directive can also listener 'input' changes.

```
import { Directive,HostListener,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[customMax]'
})
export class customDirective {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
}
  @HostListener('input',['$event'])onchange(event:any){
    let value=this.el.value;
    let lastchar = value.substr(value.length - 1);
    let bool=lastchar.match(/[0-9]/);
    if (bool){ //if last character match a regExpr
        bool=parseInt(value)>=0 && parseInt(value)<100; //and the condition required
    }
    if (!bool){ //if it does not meet the conditions
        value=value.substr(0,value.length-1);
        this.el.value=value;
        //it's necesary dispatch the event 'input' manually
        let event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
        this.el.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you to use Kendo, that simply allow you to have a min & max on its own component.

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [value]="value" [min]="0" [max]="100">
</kendo-numerictextbox>
```